Is it possible to use a literal value in a foreign key constraint anyhow?
I tried this.
CREATE TABLE entity (
  pk       serial PRIMARY KEY,
  deleted  timestamp,
  UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (pk, deleted)
);
CREATE TABLE referer(
  pk      serial PRIMARY KEY,
  entity  int,
  FOREIGN KEY (entity, NULL) REFERENCES entity(pk, deleted)
);

But it does not work.

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NULL"
LINE 4:   FOREIGN KEY (entity, NULL) REFERENCES entity(pk, deleted)
                               ^


fiddle

Not directly in any SQL variant I know.
You could add an extra column of the right type and force it to always have the desired value via constraints or triggers¹, then use that in the FK relationship.
If you want to hide the extra column from general visibility you could use an updatable view that leaves that column out. Some DBs support hidden columns which would make this easier, but I don't know if postgres does.

[1] triggers would be less efficient, but that way you could silently ignore anything put in there

A foreign key is not enforced if a column is NULL. See the documentation:

Normally, a referencing row need not satisfy the foreign key constraint if any of its referencing columns are null. If MATCH FULL is added to the foreign key declaration, a referencing row escapes satisfying the constraint only if all its referencing columns are null (so a mix of null and non-null values is guaranteed to fail a MATCH FULL constraint). If you don't want referencing rows to be able to avoid satisfying the foreign key constraint, declare the referencing column(s) as NOT NULL.

I recommend that you get rid of the NULL value for entity.deleted and use a value like infinity to indicate that a row has not been deleted yet.
Then you could create the foreign key constraint like this:
CREATE TABLE entity (
  pk       bigint    GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                     PRIMARY KEY,
  deleted  timestamp NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (pk, deleted)
);

CREATE TABLE referer(
  pk      bigint    GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                    PRIMARY KEY,
  entity  bigint    NOT NULL,
  deleted timestamp GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('infinity') STORED
                    NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (entity, timestamp) REFERENCES entity(pk, deleted)
);


One cannot insert into a STORED column, so the child table isn't much good?

@Vérace It's just there so you can define the foreign key constraint, and only entity rows with a certain deleted can be referenced. I assumed that is what OP wanted.

I had something similar already. But then I thought that referer.deleted is pretty useless, because it will be always "infinity". If I have one million rows in referer I have one million times a constant value in the database.

@Vérace Yes, it is useless, except to guarantee that the foreign key will only reference certain rows.

This has me totally stumped! At least I understood your previous question.
Please expand on what you're trying to do/learn here?
Just out of morbid curiosity, I played around with it a bit, not that I expected much.
My guess is that it's something in the SQL Parser (way above my pay grade) that forbids an FK declaration that contains anything other than references to fields in the referenced table!
So, anything like:
CREATE TABLE child
(
  pk      serial PRIMARY KEY,
  entity  int,
  FOREIGN KEY (entity, <SOMETHING_NOT_A_FIELD>) REFERENCES parent (pk, deleted)
);

will be immediately rejected by the system.
The steps a statement goes through for actually producing data are as follows (it's very involved - you require an in-depth knowledge of C to really make headway - I'm just starting to dip my toes in the water here). The images and some of the text below come from here and/or the PostgreSQL documentation:


So, to drill down a bit, the first step is the Parser which does the following:



And then after the parsing step, the statement goes to the Analyzer (see first link, first bullet point):

The main purpose of the Analyzer is to check the raw_parsetree
structure created by the parser stage.
Responsible for deeper syntax analysis.


As I said above, my guess is that somewhere here, your bizarre FK declaration is halted in its tracks!
It may pass the Lexer (NULL is a valid SQL token), but I'm fairly sure that it wouldn't get any further than the Analyzer - "Responsible for deeper syntax analysis.". That probably means looking at SQL grammars, i.e.  Backus–Naur form (BNF) (see here, and here) - that last link is to a 20,000 line C code file (even with comments, but hey...).
In short, I'd be shocked if what you're attempting (which is?) - maybe I should say, I'd be shocked if what you've written made it past an early statement processing stage.
Huge caveat about all of the above. I'm far from an expert in this area, but if you really want to delve deeper into this, you could go to the PostgreSQL lists (try on general first, they might point you to hackers) - but trying to put an FK on a constant or a NULL is, on the face of it, nonsensical and rightly rejected out of hand!
